# Shadow of Mordor won't install fully

Tags: xbox-one, middle-earth-shadow-of-mordor

So, I downloaded ME: SoM for my XB1 and the game is great, but I get to the point where in order to progress in the storyline, you go to a whole different map. This mission tells me that I only have 45% of what I need installed and I can't play any of the other game modes because I've only got 93% installed. When I go to the manage game panel, it tells me the game is installed fully. Any help?

Comment: Have you tried deleting it and re-downloading it?

Comment: Some of the installed files come from the disc, some come from updates. Even on the day of release you can still need a large download to update the game. Can you confirm if you own the physical game, or if it is online? And that you can connect to the internet with your Xbox One?

Comment: sounds like you downloaded a digital copy, but it is important to know if you have a disc. more than likely, if it's digital, the download hiccupped or something and it sounds like you need to reinstall. just dont delete your saved game files. if that doesnt fix it, let us know by updating your post, because then it's a very strange issue.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting it and then re-downloading it fixed the issue, I guess it was just a hiccup or something when it originally installed from the store.